# Problema linkeando cuentas con firebase usando distintas redes sociales

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, facebook

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion en Android Studio, utilizando Java como lenguaje nativo e intentando implementar Firebase Authentication para resolver el sistema de usuarios. Pudiendo hacerlo con Google, Facebook y Twitter.

Para cada uno de ellos estaba utilizando este bloque de codigo:

```
AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(preLoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Entonces, cuando el usuario es nuevo, funciona todo perfecto. El problema es cuando tengo un usuario ya registrado con el mail en google (asd@asd.com) y luego intento loguear con el usuario de facebook que tiene el mismo correo asociado. En este caso, la autenticacion falla.

Necesito tener usuarios unicos, no me sirve habilitar la opcion de tener varios usuarios con la misma cuenta de mail.

Segun la [documentacion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) de android, para vincular los dos usuarios y mantener el UID debemos utilizar el metodo *linkWithCredential* de la siguiente manera:

```
firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "linkWithCredential:success");
                FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                updateUI(user);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "linkWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(AnonymousAuthActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateUI(null);
            }

            // ...
        }
    });
```

Entonces, al querer seguir estos pasos, el problema es que user es null.

Ademas, suponiendo sortear este obstaculo, no veo como mergear los datos de Facebook con los de Google para almacenarlos en un unico usuario en Firebase Authentication.

Por ultimo, la intencion tambien era hacerlo con Instagram pero me parecio que era mucho mas complejo que el resto. Esto es tan asi?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Proba lo siguiente, podes utilizar `getProviderData()` para averiguar que cuentas estan vinculadas con ese usuario, y de esa forma actualizar tu UI

```
firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "linkWithCredential:success");
                FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                 for (UserInfo userInfo : user.getProviderData()) {
                   if (userInfo.getDisplayName() != null) {
                      String displayName = userInfo.getDisplayName();
                      Toast(displayName); //Ejemplo para conseguir un displayName de cualquier provider
                       }
                    }
            //updateUI(user); //-> Una vez conseguida la informacion de los proveedores, actualizas la UI con los datos que uses dentro del for
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "linkWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(AnonymousAuthActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateUI(null);
            }

            // ...
        }
    });
```

[getProviderData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#getProviderData())

> Devuelve una lista de objetos UserInfo que representa las identidades
>   vinculadas del usuario utilizando diferentes proveedores de
>   autenticación que pueden estar vinculados a su cuenta. Use esto para
>   acceder, por ejemplo, a la información del perfil básico de su usuario
>   recuperada de Facebook, independientemente de si el usuario usó el
>   inicio de sesión de Facebook para iniciar sesión en la sesión actual.

Otra posible solucion seria desloguear de todos los providers al usuario e intentarlo de nuevo

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

Comment: es que en realidad mi problema esta en que firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() da null, entonces tengo un nullPointerException, se te ocurre como podria salvar este error?

Comment: Probaste usar firebaseauthlistener ?

Comment: Sep, pero no hubo caso. Hoy pregunto al profesor de la universidad. Gracias!